# React - Focus on input using name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-redux

I have a component with input, is there any way to focus using the name?

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
    ... Some more code ...
        <input type="text" name={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onChange} autoFocus/>
    ... Some more code ...
</div>
```

On click of the parent div, I have a on click event attached to it.

```
handleClick(e) {
    // Need to focus may be using refs, but not sure how to do it.
    return this.props.onClick(this.props.name);
}
```

Comment: you should be able to do auto focus using input autoFocus property. But if you have multiple text box and all need to focus during loading last one will win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component:

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
    ... Some more code ...
        <input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }} name={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onChange} autoFocus/>
    ... Some more code ...
</div>
```

Click handler:

```
handleClick(e) {
    this.input.focus();
    return this.props.onClick(this.props.name);
}
```

---

### or

Component:

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
    ... Some more code ...
        <input type="text" ref={this.props.name} name={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onChange} autoFocus/>
    ... Some more code ...
</div>
```

Click Handler:

```
handleClick(e) {
    this.refs[this.props.name].focus();
    return this.props.onClick(this.props.name);
}
```

Comment: I think in the second method, this would refer to the div rather than the input. Tried both but no luck.

Comment: Are you getting some error message? Have you tried to add logs with `this.refs` inside `componentDidMount` to check if refs are defined?

Comment: I do not see any error, and I'm not sure how to log `this,refs` inside `componenetDidMount`

Does this work for testing?
`componentDidMount(){ console.log(this.props.name); }`

Comment: I see the refs are not being rendered 
`<input type="text" name="pets" placeholder="NO INFO FOUND" data-reactid=".0.2.0.5.0.1.$0.0.1.1">`

Comment: `ref` is an attribute of the virtual DOM, it doesn't appear on the "real" DOM.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using an extension of react, I see its loading now.

Comment: `componenetDidMount() { console.log('refs:', this.refs) }` Yes, it's useful to check if refs are defined before the component is rendered

Comment: Its logging refs Object `refs: Object {pets: input}`

Comment: I added a console log in handleClick function, `handleClick(e) { console.log(this.refs[this.props.name]); ... }` and it logged the input field. So I'm not getting why its not focusing on the input.

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: I created a separate project and that worked, I'm using 0.14.8. Something wrong with the code,  I ll debug and update if I find out. But your solution works.

Comment: This works with >15. You could try using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[this.props.name]).focus()`